# C# Async StandardInput Redirection

Tags: c#, io-redirection

I am creating WinForm application which starts a process with redirection. I am using Async method:

```
proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = commandLocation + procesName;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => AppendLine(args.Data);
proc.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => AppendLine(args.Data);

proc.Start();
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(inputText);
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

while (!proc.HasExited) //Instead of WaitForExit
{
    Thread.Sleep(100); //Because of CPU usage
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Here is AppendLine method for displaying output to richtextbox:

```
private void AppendLine(string line)
{
    if (richTextBoxOutput.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Action act = () =>
        {
            this.richTextBoxOutput.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
        };

        this.BeginInvoke(act);
    }
    else
    {
        richTextBoxOutput.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Everything works well. But when I run a console application that needs input (for example `Console.ReadLine()`), my application crashes [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD12I.png) (not responding). How can I send input to the redirected console application throughout its run?

Comment: For example when I start a simple console game which has `Console.ReadKey();` this happes: [link](http://i.imgur.com/kvjxzjR.png?1)

Comment: Do you want to send the input from the WinForms app or normally using the keyboard? How come you see the console window when you create the process with `CreateNoWindow = true`? Are you able to attach a debugger to the console application to see why it crashes? Otherwise I gave your code a quick test and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My application is like a shell. For example when I use command "ls -lah | sort" it works good. It sends input from WinForm app to sort.exe and displays result in richtextbox.
But when I start application which is asking me for example for a line of text, it fails. I am not able to write input while process is running and already gave me some output (shown in screenshot). Typically, it fails in every application that contains ReadKey() or ReadLine().

Comment: Another thing is, that my application just freezes and Windows show "Application stopped working." [link](http://i.imgur.com/TtcPaMO.png). When I close these dialogs, my application unfreeze and works again but process has exited.
Thank you for your time and helping me.

Comment: Well, since I can't replicate the issue, the only thing I can suggest is to add some exception handling/logging to the crashing application or attach a debugger to it to figure out what exactly is going wrong. You might also be able to get some information from the Windows Event log.